# Can't convert complex to float Error on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, area, complex-numbers

I wrote a code for calculating Area of Triangle

```
a = float(input("Enter the first side of triangle: \n"))
b = float(input("Enter the second side of triangle: \n"))
c = float(input("Enter the thrid side of triangle: \n"))

s = (a+b+c) / 2

area = (s*(s-a) * (s-b) * (s-c)) ** 0.5

print("The area of triangle is %0.3f" %area)
```

My input values that I used were: 25, 4556, 5544

The error i received was:

```
print("The area of triangle is %0.3f" %area)
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

Can some body please help me with the problem? My code works fine when I input small numbers, like (5,6,7). Using Pycharm as my IDE.

Comment: `25, 4556, 5544` is not a valid triangle. The two shorter sides aren't long enough. It's like trying to make a triangle where one side has a length 1, the 2nd side has a length of 3, and the third side has a length of 1 thousand. It obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Can you draw such a triangle?

Comment: @ParasKumar: Check my answer. If that helps, [don't forget to accept  it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Give me some 4D graph paper...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't work because the input sides do not form a triangle - `25 + 4556 < 5544`. As such, the term `s-c` is negative, due to which computing the square root returns complex number.

To be sure you have valid sides, add an assertion/validation after you take the values for a, b, c which checks:

```
assert a+b+c > 2*max(a, b, c)
```

This basically ensures that sum of the two smaller sides is greater than the largest side.

---

As an aside, you can also validate that your sides are all positive:

```
assert all(x>0 for x in (a, b, c))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.